# Как назвать предложения вида "В текст добавлена запятая"?

Tags: глаголы, терминология

Делаю руководство по написанию журнала изменений. Пытаюсь сформулировать правило, что записи должны быть следующего вида: "В коде исправлена ошибка", "В приложение добавлен диалог" и т.д.

А такие варианты запрещены: "Я исправил ошибку", "Исправил ошибку", "Исправить ошибку", "Исправление ошибки".

В общем чтобы в формулировках был глагол совершённого вида в прошедшем времени в определенной форме без указания на конкретное лицо. Как это правильно сформулировать?

Comment: Может быть, *безличное?*

Comment: Спасибо! Наверное, да, безличное. Только не хватает ещё каких-то уточнений. Потому что судя по примерам они могут быть очень разными https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Безличные_предложения

Comment: Ну ещё можно добавить, что "добавлена" ***страдательное*** причастие (краткое).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно предположить, что здесь должен использоваться **единственный вариант** – краткая форма страдательного причастия прошедшего времени: ***ошибка исправлена, диалог добавлен.***

**Причастие** считается особой формой глагола (существует четыре вида причастий). **Страдательное причастие прошедшего времени**  обозначает  действие, которое  было совершено с предметом, закончено к настоящему времени, но признаки которого сохраняются в нем.

**Краткая форма** причастия в предложении является **сказуемым**, как и обычный глагол, при этом действующее лицо указывать не следует (не имеет значения, кем исправлена ошибка).

Таким образом, формулировка может выглядеть так. В журнале изменений при указании действия используется краткая форма страдательного причастия прошедшего времени (без указания действующего лица): ***ошибка исправлена, диалог добавлен.***